Localization not working for the Today button in @mui/x-date-pickers's LocalizationProvider
I need the button "today" in the @mui/x-date-pickers in my app as shown in their documentation (here).
There's a problem with the localization. I'm passing the "fr" adapterLocale to the LocalizationProvider but it's still displaying the date in english.
I made this stackblitz to reproduce the issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tfmv7t?file=Demo.tsx

Change Demo.tsx as below
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale={'es'}
localeText={deDE.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}>
  <StaticDatePicker
    defaultValue={dayjs('2022-04-17')}
    slotProps={{
      actionBar: {
        actions: ['today'],
      },
    }}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>

Use these imports
import "dayjs/locale/es";
import { deDE } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/locales';
You can find the reference here

Thanks. I will try it. But the example of code provided in the official doc doesn't use a localeText attribute (doc: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/adapters-locale/#with-date-fns)

Issue was you were using dayjs adapter and date-fns locale.
Using dayjs locale, the month name translates.
But for translating other texts localeText is used
